# Renumbering windows in tmux

Tags: tmux

I frequently end up with more than ten windows in tmux. Later on, I close some of my older ones. Is there a way to renumber, say window 15, to window 3 (which doesn't exist anymore)? Or to `pack` them all up again, so that there are no empty slots? I'd like to do this because it is difficult to jump to higher numbered windows, because you can't do `Ctrl+B, 15`. I have to use `Ctrl+B, w` to list the windows and then type the letter corresponding to the window I want to open.

I know that I can swap windows. For example, I could create a new window (`Ctrl+B, c`) which would open in the empty slot 3. I can then `swapw` window 15 and window 3 and then close window 15. Obviously, this is a tedious approach.

How do you manage many windows in tmux?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469612/how-do-i-make-tmux-reorder-windows-when-one-is-deleted

Answer (score 202, accepted):

Looks like you need this:

> ```
> move-window [-rdk] [-s src-window] [-t dst-window]
>               (alias: movew)
>         This is similar to link-window, except the window at src-window
>         is moved to dst-window.  With -r, all windows in the session are
>         renumbered in sequential order, respecting the base-index option.
> ```

Calling `movew` without parameters moves current window to first free position. `movew -r` will renumber all the windows at once.

Comment: For those who need a more explicit instruction: `ctrl b` `:` then enter `move-window -r` (where `ctrl b` is the default prefix key)

Comment: BTW, from within the tmux session, you can execute a tmux command in any window/shell and it'll do the operation on the containing tmux session. So a simple `tmux move-window -r` would do the same thing without the need to use the tmux prefox key combination.

Answer (score 142):

*tmux* 1.7 has a couple of features that can help establish and maintain gapless/packed window numbers:

- The `move-window` command learned a new `-r` option that will renumber all the windows in a session (either the current session, or one specified with the `-t` option).

  If you have a set of windows like { 1:A, 4:B, 15:C }, then you can run `move-window -r` to renumber them to { 1:A, 2:B, 3:C } (they will start with your `base-index`; 1 in this example).
- When the `renumber-windows` session option is enabled, *tmux* will automatically renumber the windows of a session (as with `move-window -r`) after any window is closed.

  If you like this behavior, you can turn it on in the global value so that all sessions that to not override it will automatically have it enabled:

  ```
  set-option -g renumber-windows on
  ```

Comment: Finally! I've been searching for this `renumber-windows` option for ages! Always bugged me that new windows open on the "left" because I close some before.

Comment: For some odd reason `renumber-windows` does not update the window numbers, why might this be?

Answer (score 22):

I often find myself in a situation where I have gaps in between window numbers, for example a session with windows:

```
1 3 4 8 9 13
```

I wrote a tmux script to reorder them without changing their respective order nor activating the 'renumbering-windows' option. The result:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Put the following in your .tmux.conf:

```
bind R                                      \
    set -g renumber-windows on\;            \
    new-window\; kill-window\;              \
    set -g renumber-windows off\;           \
    display-message "Windows reordered..."
```

Hit [PREFIX]-R to reorder windows (or change the binding).

I'm currently running tmux 1.9a.

The above can be replaced  with the much simpler:

```
bind R                                      \
    move-window -r\;                        \
    display-message "Windows reordered..."
```

Comment: Is this different from running "move-window -r"?

Comment: No it is not. I just didn't know about the -r option to move-window :) never too late to learn, thx!

Answer (score 20):

If you just need windows to always renumber when one is killed, you can use this in `.tmux.conf`:

```
set-option -g renumber-windows on
```

Don't forget to reload the config with

```
tmux source ~/.tmux.conf          # default config file
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 13):

The previous answers are all fine, but here's a concise solution if all you want is to shuffle a small number of windows now and again.

```
move-window -t <number>
```

will move the current window to a new window number (which must not already be occupied).  To swap two windows, you temporarily move one window to a new number first.  e.g. to swap windows 3 and 5:

```
move-window -s 3 -t 99
move-window -s 5 -t 3
move-window -s 99 -t 5
```