# tmux session_name count

Tags: tmux

Let's say that I created four new `tmux` sessions (1, 2, 3, and 4). Now, I kill every window in session 2. `tmux list-session` only show that 1, 3, and 4 are active.  If I create a new `tmux` session, it is named 5.

*How can I make realise `tmux` that "session 2" (or just the number 2) can be recycled?*

Of course, I can rename session 5 to session 2 but that's an extra command and I am lazy.

Note that I am talking here about *sessions* and not [*windows* numbering](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21742/10526). I know about `renumber-windows`.

Answer (score 4):

This was discussed on the tmux mailing list at the time that [renumber-windows was introduced](http://sourceforge.net/p/tmux/mailman/message/29255929/), but looking at [session.c](http://sourceforge.net/p/tmux/tmux-code/ci/master/tree/session.c) it doesn't appear to have been implemented yet.

Comment: @Sardathrion Updated: not any more helpful, unfortunately...

Comment: No, that is helpful.  It's information I did not have before. ^_~